# Import parametres of main to paint method

Tags: java, netbeans, paint, graphics2d

I want to use some arrays of main to paint method. For example I need arrays x[] and y[] used by paint method. Should I implement the code to the method or the constructor?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.Math.pow;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class filtra extends JFrame{


  public filtra(){

    super();
  }

  @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        for(int c=1; c<size; c++){
         g.drawLine(x[i-1],y[i-1],x[i],y[i]); 
        }
  }  

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
// [...]  in main i have some code. For example i want to use arrays x[i] and y[i] for visualization...

                   filtra frame = new filtra();
                   frame.setSize(200,200);
                   frame.setVisible(true);         

    }
}
```

i have a java class, main, in net beans, where i calculate 10000 or 10000000 double values, and i store them in x[] and y[] . I want to make a simple graph of these double values in a x-y axis in blue colour points connected by What's the simplest way to do it (use the x[] y[] of the main, in paint method and loop 0-100000 to paint the points and lines)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your problem but, if you want to access arrays for the main method in your paint method then try this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.Math.pow;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class filtra extends JFrame{
//declare arrays here
static int[] x=new int[10];
static int[] y=new int[10];
public filtra(){

   super();
}


public void paint(Graphics g){
       int size=10;
    for(int c=1; c<size; c++){
     g.drawLine(x[i-1],y[i-1],x[i],y[i]); 
    }
  }  

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
               //do something with arrays example:
               x[1]=554;                   
               y[1]=248;

               filtra frame = new filtra();
               frame.setSize(200,200);
               frame.setVisible(true);         

   }
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

make a setter method in your filtra class.

```
private int[] x;
private int[] y;
public void setData(int[] x, int[] y) {
     this.x=x;
     this.y=y;
}
```

and use it in main, this way, you can start many instances of your JFrame each with different data painted, it could be usefull for you.